# UITableView does not populate with data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to make a simple UITableView with custom cells (including two labels and one image view) but I can't get the table to be populated with data.

I have created the following struct for my data:

```
struct feed {
  var title: String
  var subtitle: String
  var image: String
}
```

and here I have defined some sample data:

```
var myfeed = [feed(title: "Test Feed", subtitle: "Welcome to feedFeed", image: "https://www.demo.com/imnage1.png"), feed(title: "Number 2", subtitle: "Demo?", image: "https://www.demo.com/imnage2.png")]
```

I have created an UITableView in my Storyboard, have configured the Custom cell and am using the Cell identifier "LabelCell".
I have created a separate cocoaTouchclass file for the UITableViewCell class:

```
import UIKit

class ehappyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var headlineTitleLabel: UILabel! 
    @IBOutlet weak var headlineTextLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var headlineImageView: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()
       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableViewCell, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
           { 
              return 100.0;//Choose your custom row height
            }
         // Initialization code
    }    

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

In my ViewController file I have the following code:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!    

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myfeed.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableViwq: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:ehappyTableViewCell = self.table.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", for: indexPath) as! ehappyTableViewCell!

        let headline = myfeed[indexPath.row]
        cell.headlineTitleLabel?.text = headline.title
        cell.headlineTextLabel?.text = headline.subtitle
        let urlWithoutHTTP = headline.image
        let httpAddition = "https:"
        let addition = "\(httpAddition)\(urlWithoutHTTP)"

        let url = URL(string: addition)

        DispatchQueue.global().async {
           let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                cell.headlineImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }
        }
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 140.0;//Choose your custom row height
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.table.delegate = self
        self.table.dataSource = self
    }
```

When I run the app the table will not populate with the sample data I have created. 
Any suggestions on what I can do?

Comment: where you have set your cell Identifier -> LabelCell ? You are using prototype cell of different cell xib ?

Comment: In the Storyboard I habe set the cell identifier to “LabelCell”

Comment: check myfeed.count t may be zero

Comment: Unrelated but delete the entire `awakeFromNib` method in the custom cell. The nested table view delegate method is pointless and will never be called. And name classes with starting capital letter. And never load data with synchronous API `Data(contentsOf` from a remote URL, not even in a background thread. That's very bad practice.

Comment: Did you register your custom class??

Comment: myfeed.count is not zero

Comment: How should I register the class?

Answer (score 1):

- If your cell is an **xib** then you **have to register** the cell by writing the following code in the **viewDidLoad**

  `self.table.register(UINib(nibName: "ehappyTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "LabelCell")`
- If it is designed inside the viewcontroller in storyboard then **no need to register**
- Check if delegate and dataSource are given
- Try replacing the line with following line

  `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell") as? ehappyTableViewCell`